# Accessing parameter value in route annotation

Tags: symfony

My services.yaml looks like:

```html
parameters:
  domain:
    en: mydomain.com
```

Now I want to use that parameter in a route annotation:

```html
/**
 * @Route("/page", name="web_page_en", host="{domain}", requirements={"domain"="%domain.en%"} )
 */
```

But somehow I cannot access the domain.en-parameter. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I remember parameters can not be structured. If you want to use `domain.en` as a parameter key in code, annotations and other places of your app it's necessary to define parameters like this

```
parameters:
  domain.en: mydomain.com
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be the problem/solution.